# How to fix syntax error at or near “CREATE” in psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

please why is this code not working?

```
nodelogin-# CREATE TABLE user
nodelogin-# (id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
nodelogin(# name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
nodelogin(# email VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
nodelogin(# password VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
nodelogin(# UNIQUE (email));
```

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 2: CREATE TABLE user
        ^
```

Comment: You’re in the middle of another command. Start fresh. The - in the prompt means you’re in the middle of things. It should show = instead

Comment: Incidentally, I found these tips useful: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_varchar.28n.29_by_default

Answer (score 1):

`user` is a reserved [key word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in PostgreSQL. Basically, PostgreSQL doesn't like the name. If you try a different name (`user2`, `user_`, `comp_user`) it should work